# Missing Objects after Rendering

Tags: rendering, camera

**What did I do wrong, that Blender do not renders all objects?**

I can see everything in the 3D rendering viewport, but when I render my scene, the closest objects are missing. In the camera settings I toggled clipping back and forward, but it doesn't matter.

Does somebody have a clue?

[image: rendered][image: 3D view]

Comment: Found the solution. Had to select objects and in Edit mode > W > Clear all restrict render. And now it renders properly! Don't know why and how. ha

Comment: You could write this as an answer and mark it as accepted so that this question is answered and closed. Keeps things cleaner than having a bunch of unsanswered questions that are in fact solved.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Had to select objects and in Edit mode > W > Clear all restrict render.